# Adding SPFieldType.File to a custom list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, splist

When I try to add a File type field to a custom list I get

`System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object`

```
Guid listGuid = adminWeb.Lists.Add(queueListName, "DotNetNuke Document Queue", SPListTemplateType.GenericList);

queueList = adminWeb.Lists[listGuid];
queueList.Fields.Add("Status", SPFieldType.File, false);

queueList.Update();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that you can have a "File" field. If you look in the UI, there is no "File" field type for custom/generic list.

If you need 1 file per item and it is mandatory, then you should be using a document library.

If you need more than 1 file per list item, then file attachments is the way to go.

Comment: is there way to copy a file from a document library to a different one without duplicating the file?

Comment: there is the "Link to document" content type, or the "Send to other location" feature (but that does create a copy)